# Problem of printing ABC... and a number in Java

Tags: java, error-handling

This is the function I set:

```
public int printABCNum(p) {
    char textinfo = 65;
    String textValue = "";
        while (textinfo < 91) {
            textValue+=textinfo;
            textinfo++;
        }
        System.out.println(textValue + Integer.toString(p));
```

Eclipse (a text editor) says that there is a problem with `public int printABCNum(p)` bit. Basically I'm trying to do is run a function printing "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and an integer. I'm new to Java and is not good 'enough' at programming with it and finding bugs, so please help!

Comment: Please post the whole method. You are missing at least a curly brace. And if that's the only thing present in your code that you didn't post here, the problem is obvious: the method requires that you return an int, but you are merely printing a String. So you need to return an int or define the return type as void. Also you forgot to state the type of the argument p.

Comment: Read about the difference between IDE and Text editor :)

Comment: The problem is that `printABCNum(p)` should be -> `printABCNum(int p)`

Comment: At least I've fixed the int p and p, and I did the curly brackets, just haven't included it.

Comment: And I've also written the method in which I call the function.

Comment: @anastaciu Thanks, but no thanks, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `p` parameter of your `printABCNum` function is missing a type. Based on context it should be an `int`. Another problem is your function return type is defined to `int`, but you haven't returned any value.

Your code should be:

```
public void printABCNum(int p) {
    char textinfo = 65;
    String textValue = "";
    while (textinfo < 91) {
        textValue += textinfo;
        textinfo++;
    }
    System.out.println(textValue + p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, there are more problems on the ```public void printABCNum(int p) {``` bit, so please help on that.

Comment: Hmm, is your method placed inside a class?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's also in a ```public static void main(String[] args)```.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's in `public static void main`?". If you just placed a function inside another function in won't work, because nested function declarations aren't allowed in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a few things wrong here.

1. You shouldn't have a return type `int` if you are not returning anything.
2. The parameter needs to have a type, as such: `int p`

Other than that looks fine. Take a look below at full answer that worked for me.

```java
public void printABCNum(int p) {
    char textinfo = 65;
    String textValue = "";
    while (textinfo < 91) {
        textValue+=textinfo;
        textinfo++;
    }
    System.out.println(textValue + Integer.toString(p));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that's the same as the top one except the ```Integer.toString```. I also have more problems with it such as the semicolon on the ```String textValue = "";``` part and still has problems on the part declaring the function.